# Vision with camera live stream and ARKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

I'd like to implement an scenario like this: to use a camera live stream with `Vision` to detect some rectangles, then to process this output according to some logic, then to display AR elements according to the logic output with `ARKit`.

The examples I've found don't cover this full process from `Vision` live stream detection to `ARKit` with `SpriteKit`, but for those "steps" separatedly. The one I found for live stream with `Vision` is using a `UIImageView` for that. Other ones I found for `ARKit` with `SpriteKit` are using an `ARSKView` for that.

Which the best way to integrate all this in a stepped process `Vision` -> logic -> `ARKit` would be?